# How to replace a layer?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, delete

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.2.
I'm using the next Python code to show some records of an attribute table:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"F:ArcGIS\Trab\Model\Lin_150_tr.shp", "lyr5")  
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr5", "NEW_SELECTION", """FID IN (2,10,200,323,349,384,433)""")
```

But I'm not able to run my Python script again because appears an error like "lyr5 already exists". So I use a funtion:
arcpy.Delete_management(lyr5)
but it gives me an error *NameError: name 'lyr5' is not defined*.

- What can I do to solve this problem, updating my layers, without loss
  my original shapefile called Lin_150_tr.shp?
- May I do a copy of this shapefile before to do
  SelectLayerByAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close. The problem is that if you enter `arcpy.Delete_management(lyr5)` you tell python to delete a variable. You haven't saved your layer as a variable, this is why the error message shows up. Try this:

```
arcpy.Delete_management("lyr5")
```

or:

```
lyr5 = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"F:ArcGIS\Trab\Model\Lin_150_tr.shp", "lyr5") 
arcpy.Delete_management(lyr5)
```

Comment: When I try to do the same on a funcion arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("02_Re.xlsx", "c_re_otim.dbf", "Re_Lo") it's not possible.. It gives error.. How can I do?

Comment: ok first of all it would be nice of you to give a feedback on the answer. did it work, did you encounter any other problems? as for your comment, this is a different topic, which requires a new question.